# Baccarat game with arrays throws exception after a few rounds

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I have almost completed the game, but I am not sure why it goes down after a few rounds. I believe it has something to do with the way the deck class is written. It was provided by the teacher, but I may need to fix it.

I thought maybe after a few rounds, the arrays were getting too full or something, so I tried adding a method to clear them out. This did not work, and I don't think it is the problem, but I am not sure.

```
class deck{

    private String [] cards = {"A","K","Q","J","10","9","8","7","6","5","4","3","2"};
    private int cardCount = 1;
    private boolean isShuffled = false;

    //**********Shuffle cards method****************************
    private void shuffleCards(){//shuffle cards method

        for (int i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
            int index = (int)(Math.random() * 13);
            String temp = cards[i];
            cards[i] = cards[index];
            cards[index] = temp;
        }
        isShuffled = true;
    }

    //********Ensure the cards get shuffled before dealing******
    public String getCards(){

        if (isShuffled == true){
            cardCount++;
            return cards[cardCount];
        }
        else {
            shuffleCards();//shuffle if they have not
            cardCount++;
            return cards[cardCount];
        }
    }

    //********Show cards method*********************************
    public void showCards(String [] theirCards){

        for (int i = 0; i < theirCards.length; i++) {
            if(theirCards[i] == null){
                continue;
            }
            System.out.print(theirCards[i] + " ");
        }
    }

    public void clearCards(){
        cards = null;
        cards = null;
    }

    //*******Card value method**********************************
    public int getCardValues(String tempChar){

        int indValues = 1;

        switch (tempChar){
            case "A": indValues = 1; break;
             blah blah blah
            case "3": indValues = 3; break;
            case "2": indValues = 2;

        }
        return indValues;
    }
}
```

I expect the game to keep looping until I quit or run out of money through betting, but instead, after about 3 games, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 13
    at deck.getCards(Baccarat.java:248)
    at playerObjects.setComputersCards(Baccarat.java:177)
    at Baccarat.main(Baccarat.java:19)
```

Comment: The error says that the error is on line 248.  What is on line 248?  I think it is `return cards[cardCount];`.  The error says `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.  That means that the `cardCount` is not a valid index for the array.  Do you know why that could be?

Comment: Is it possible that you're reusing the same instance of the `deck` class for each game, but that you're meant to create a new instance for each game? I don't know the rules of baccarat, but that would be my first guess.

Comment: it is return cards[cardCount] as you said. it looks like cardcount is initialized to 1, and getCards increments it by one and returns cards[cardCount]. I think perhaps its a way to move through the array to get a unique card each time.

Comment: I instantiate the objects once, so I am reusing the deck, but I tried just now to loop instantiating the deck and it did not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two obvious problems:

First, cardCount is initialized to 1 (as previously mentioned).
Second, in method getCards(), cardCount is incremented before returning a card.
To fix this you should initialize cardCount to -1 instead of 1.

As it is now, you are always skipping the first two cards in your deck so you have only 11 cards, not the 13 you are assuming, which is probably why you're going over the index on about the third round -- Baccarat hands are typically 2 to 3 cards each to the player and the bank so that adds up.

Solution

First, you should initialize cardCount to -1.
Second, as a failsafe you should modify the getCards() method to test your cardCount and if it is at 12 already consider setting it to -1 and shuffling the cards again before doing the increment/return card.  In other words, have the deck manage itself to avoid the index out of bounds.

Comment: That made a huge difference. I can play indefinitely now. Thank you!